# I want to create a table in database but I want the name of the table to be a date. But it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to create a table using MySQLI and PHP but I want the name of the table in the database to be a date. But it doesn't want to create such a table why?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bukowski";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$data=date('Y-m-d');

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE ".$data." (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Creating a table with a date sounds like a database design problem.

Comment: I would use [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) naming instead of formatted date for table name.